# iPhone: App name at app store & bundle name must be similar?

Tags: iphone, app-store, bundle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone: Can I use simple name for bundle name and bundle display name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450740/iphone-can-i-use-simple-name-for-bundle-name-and-bundle-display-name)

It is reasonable that `app name at app store` and `bundle display name(name on home screen)` must be similar.
Because both of them are displayed to users.

But `bundle name` is not displayed to users.
Do you have to make `bundle name` similar to `app name at app store`, too?

Comment: @Mehul no. they are different question.

Comment: @Mehul I want to know if i can use `Dog Personalizer` for `bundle name` in this question. I want know if i can use `Helper` for `bundle display name` in the question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450740/iphone-can-i-use-simple-name-for-bundle-name-and-bundle-display-name . Please see basvk's answer and its comment, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451697/709950 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't have to be exactly similar.
For instance the name of your app in the appstore could be: `Tweet Helper Unlimited Genuine Edition`. Your bundle-name can be something like: `Tweet Helper Unlimited` and your bundle display name `Tweet Helper`. This would be okay.

Ofcourse they should be 'almost' similar, as long as the don't mismatch like so:
Appstore name: `Tweet Helper Unlimited Genuine Edition`, whilst the bundle (displayname) is something like `Dog Personalizer`. This'll get your app rejected.

You catch my drift?

Comment: Sorry, the title of the question was not accurate. I know the following will be rejected.
Appstore name: `Tweet Helper Unlimited Genuine Edition`,
bundle-name: Tweet Helper Unlimited,
bundle display name:  Dog Personalizer.
My question is, will the following be rejected or not.
Appstore name: `Tweet Helper Unlimited Genuine Edition`,
bundle-name: Dog Personalizer,
bundle display name: Tweet Helper.

Answer (score 1):

`Bundle Display` name of your application and Name which you have entered in **iTunesConnect** should be same. Apple may be reject your application if both are different. Different `Bundle Display` name and Name of your application on app store may be a cause of confusion for user. Thats why apple prevent this.

Comment: incorrect, the bundle name is not shown anywhere. The app name you enter in iTunes connect, is the name shown in the appstore.

Comment: Ok @basvk -  Thanks for correcting me....i have edited my answer, you can edit my answer if it wrong yet...